# Passing correct model to partial view

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, partial-views

I have been looking at this error for quite some time, and can't seem to figure out what I might have done wrong.

I have a partial view which is added like this:

```
        <% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/ForumPosts/ForumPostCreateForm.ascx", ViewData.Model); %>
```

And the top of the partial view looks like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<xxxx.Web.Controllers.ForumThreadsController.ForumThreadFormViewModel>" %>
```

The error I receive is the following:

*The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'xxx.Core.ForumThread', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'xxx.Web.Controllers.ForumThreadsController+ForumThreadFormViewModel'.*

If am not mistaken both takes the model called ForumThread, but apparently I must have missed something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If am not mistaken both takes the
>   model called ForumThread...

According to the code you posted, the partial view takes a `xxxx.Web.Controllers.ForumThreadsController.ForumThreadFormViewModel`. Either change the top of your partial view, or find some way to pass a `ForumThreadFormViewModel` along on a `ForumThread` object.

Another solution would be to use `RenderAction` to allow an action to generate the `ForumThreadFormViewModel` you want.

Answer (score 4):

You must need to insure about what you are going to pass model into your partial view ,
try to pass a new object of model into partial view

Answer (score 1):

Please, make sure that your Model is of type xxxx.Web.Controllers.ForumThreadsController.ForumThreadFormViewModel

To check this, look at the point in your controller where its returning the View.
The object that you are putting into the method should be of type ForumThreadFormViewModel